# Invariant-stroke-thickness with ScaleTransform in WPF Drawing/DrawingVisual

Tags: wpf

To improve performances, I want to use DrawingVisual objects instead of Shapes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/using-drawingvisual-objects?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

But I cannot figure out how to make the stroke invariant to scale transformations.

I found information ([Invariant stroke thickness of Path regardless of the scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724139/invariant-stroke-thickness-of-path-regardless-of-the-scale)) recommending using Path instead of lines, but Path is a Shape and is incompatible with Drawing.

**Is there a way to have a DrawingVisual with children scalable by transformation but maintaining the stroke thickness regardless of the scaling factor?**

Comment: Clemens answer is the way to go but I have to ask: are you sure that shapes are really slowing down performance?  You would have to be drawing an awful lot of them for that to be the case.  In the very least did you try using Path objects instead of the specific shape classes?

Comment: @Joe Now that I can do it in both ways, I will make some comparisons. My application is not a game, however it must draw tens of thousands of line segments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still have to transform Geometries instead of Drawings.

An example:

```
var transform = new ScaleTransform(10, 10);

using (var dc = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    dc.DrawGeometry(
        Brushes.AliceBlue,
        new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3),
        new RectangleGeometry
        {
            Rect = new Rect(5, 2, 15, 10),
            Transform = transform
        });

    dc.DrawGeometry(
        Brushes.Beige,
        new Pen(Brushes.Navy, 3),
        new EllipseGeometry
        {
            Center = new Point(12, 10),
            RadiusX = 5,
            RadiusY = 5,
            Transform = transform
        });
}
```

If the scaling factors are changing later, you do not need to redraw anything. Just set the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties of the ScaleTransform that was initially assigned to the `Transform` properties of the Geometries.

Result:

[image]